# Sql Server Group by subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have a database of sales transactions that have sales of multiple items identified by a  unique 'sale number' in the salenum field. Some sales are taxable and are identified by a code field with the value 'T'.  The non taxed sale just omits the 'T' value to indicate it is a non taxed transaction.

```
QUANTITY      PARTN     COST     PRICE    CODE  SALENUM
3           SAS6895     2.38       9.99     D   411436
1           GELBKP      7.4458    11.5409   D   411436
3           BRW.5       0.1471     0.228    D   411436
1           GWG        24.5668    45.00     D   411436
1           MODC4       1.3767     3.5      D   411436
1           GPFQ        6.9969    10.8451   D   411436
1           Tax         6.605      6.605    T   411436
1           OTC         0.4144     0.99     D   411437
1           S777        1.71       2.6505   D   411437
```

In the salnumber series 411436 code T shows that this sale was taxed.  salenumber 411437 omits the T so this is an exempt sale.

What I want to do is query the table and sum the transaction grouped by salenumber as taxable sales and then another query that show exempt sales.

```
select sum(quantity*price) as total from business where date = '8/28/2014'
group by salenum
```

will show both types but I can't filter by the Tax  I think this could be done with a subquery but I am lost at this point on the syntax.

Thanks in Advanced

PS, I studied the help section on how to clearly state my question so feed back would be appreciated so I can be a better member of this forum

Comment: So taxable means at least one of the records for that SaleNum has Code = T, and exempt means none of them has Code = T?

Comment: (1) Please tag your question with the database you are using (I am replacing the database tags with the generic "sql").  (2) Please specify what you want the output to look like.  Your question is vague.

Comment: Taxable means that the entire group is classified and a taxed sale

Answer (score 1):

If you want two rows, one for taxable and one for non-taxable, then you can use two levels of aggregation.  For instance, to get the results on two different rows:

```
select IsTaxable, sum(sumqp)
from (select salenum, sum(quantity * price) as sumqp,
             max(case when code = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) as IsTaxable
      from transactions t
      group by salenum
     ) t
group by IsTaxable;
```

Comment: Gordon,  do you have a good reference to this query syntax that I could study?

Comment: @brucemccampbell - this is sql, any book about sql describes the syntax.

Comment: @brucemccampbell . . . Can't ask me.  I write books on this subject and am not supposed to push them on this forum ;)

Comment: Don't have to ask you now, I just bought your book  :)

Answer (score 0):

Also can calculating the two value to two column

```
select salenum, sum(CASE code WHEN 'T' THEN quantity * price ELSE 0 END) as TaxedAmount,
                sum(CASE code WHEN 'D' THEN quantity * price ELSE 0 END) as NoTaxedAmount
      from transactions t
group by salenum
```